# Kubernetes Pod Termination doesn't happen immediately, have to wait until grace period expires

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I have a helm chart that has one deployment/pod and one service. I set the deployment terminationGracePeriodSeconds to 300s.
I didn't have any pod lifecycle hook, so if I terminate the pod, the pod should terminate immediately. However, now the pod will determine until my grace period ends!

Below is the deployment template for my pod:

```
$ kubectl get pod hpa-poc---jcc-7dbbd66d86-xtfc5 -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-01T18:12:34Z"
  generateName: hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86-
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: hpa-poc
    app.kubernetes.io/name: -
    pod-template-hash: 7dbbd66d86
  name: hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86-xtfc5
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86
    uid: 66db29d8-9e2d-4097-94fc-b0b827466e10
  resourceVersion: "127938945"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86-xtfc5
  uid: 82ed4134-95de-4093-843b-438e94e408dd
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: _CONFIG_LINK
      value: xxx
    - name: _USERNAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: username
          name: hpa-jcc-poc
    - name: _PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: password
          name: hpa-jcc-poc
    image: xxx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: -
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: 8Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 2Gi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-hzmwh
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: xxx
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-hzmwh
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-hzmwh
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-02-01T18:12:34Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-02-01T18:12:36Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-02-01T18:12:36Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-02-01T18:12:34Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://c4c969ec149f43ff4494339930c8f0640d897b461060dd810c63a5d1f17fdc47
    image: xxx
    imageID: xxx
    lastState: {}
    name: -
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2021-02-01T18:12:35Z"
  hostIP: 10.0.35.137
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.0.21.35
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2021-02-01T18:12:34Z"
```

When I tried to terminate the pod (I used `helm delete` command), you can see in the time, it terminated after 5 min which is the grace period time.

```
$ helm delete hpa-poc
release "hpa-poc" uninstalled
$ kubectl get pod -w | grep hpa
hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86-xtfc5         1/1     Terminating   0          3h10m
hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86-xtfc5         0/1     Terminating   0          3h15m
hpa-poc-jcc-7dbbd66d86-xtfc5         0/1     Terminating   0          3h15m
```

So I suspect it's something for my pod/container configuration issue. Because I have tried with the other simple Java App deployment and it can terminate immediately once I terminate the pod.

BTW, I am using AWS EKS Cluster. Not sure its AWS specific as well.

So any suggestions?

Comment: If you are pushing container/application/pod logs to any logging system, then what do you see in logs  of such delayed terminated container/application/pod?

Comment: I'm more inclined to the idea that your `Java` application is unable to catch the `SIGTERM` sent by `kubelet` rather than there is an issue with `Pod` or `Container`. That's why it's killed after 300 seconds (when `SIGKILL` is sent). You can read more about it for example here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the issue. When I exec into the container, I noticed there is one process running, which is the tailing log process.

So, I need to kill the process and add that into the prestop hook. After that, my container can shut down immediately.

Comment: Can you share your exact changes with a yaml example to complete the answer?